# Question regarding Birthday Paradox

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

If there are 100 people in a room then what is the probability that at least 2 of them share birthdays? I read that answer should be $1-\left(\frac{365!}{265!\times365^{100}} \right)$, and I understood why it is so.

However if I solve it another way I am getting the wrong answer. If we think of the problem as assigning birthdays to people, then there are ${365 \choose 100}$ ways to assign each person with a different birthday and ${464 \choose 100}$ ways so that one birthday could be assigned to more than one person. So why the following equation gives me the wrong answer:
$$1-\frac{{365 \choose 100}}{{464 \choose 100}}$$

I don't understand why the order of people matters in this question.

Comment: Where do you get $\binom{464}{100}$ from?

Comment: If we consider a binary sequence of 100 0s and 364 1s, then number of 0s to the left of leftmost 1 will give the number of people assigned the birthday 1st January and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the persons are **distinguishable** objects.

To understand the flaw in your reasoning consider this extreme example. According to your solution there's only one configuration in which all people are born on 1 January, which is right. However again according to your solution there is a single configuration in which one person is born on 2 January and the rest are on 1 January. But in reality there are 100 such configurations, as the the first person can be born on 2 January, then the second and so on.

To illustrate it even better according to your solution the probability that all people are born on 1 January is same as the probability that they are born on 1 January, 2 January, 3 January ... Now imagine the first person coming then there's a $\frac{1}{365}$ chance the first configuration is satisfied, but there's $\frac{100}{365}$ the second one is satisfied. Similarly for the second person you have $\frac{1}{365}$ chance the first confifuration is true, while $\frac{99}{365}$ the second one is.

Comment: I got your point that my solution will be wrong as persons are distinguishable objects and I am not considering which person is born on which day. However I fail to understand how that is relevant when all we care is that all birthdays in the set should be different.

Comment: @shiva As mentioned above you are counting too many configurations as one, when in fact they are different. What you are doing can be put as this: You tell everybody to write down their birthday and then you collect the papers and you only check them. Now imagine the following let's the first person be born on 2 January and the rest on 1 January. Also let the second one be born on 2 January and the rest on 1 January. According to your method these two are **same**, but in fact they are obviously different.

Comment: So if I am counting them as one configuration in the numerator, then I am doing the same in the denominator as well, so doesn't it cancel out? Sorry but I am still a little confused.

Comment: @shiva Is $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: will that solution be correct if people were indistinguishable?

Comment: @shiva Yeah, but I'm not sure to what real-life situation it would translate